# visualizing activations of layers in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, activation-function

I have a layer, `layer3`, that is of type:

```
Tensor("vgg_16/conv3/conv3_3/Relu:0", shape=(1, 500, 700, 120), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:0)
```

I'd like to visualize the activations of this layer. How can I process `layer3` to do that? What would I have to add to `tf.summary.histogram()` to visualize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, define your summary over the required layer:

```
tf.summary.histogram("layer3_hist_summary", layer3)
```

Next define the summary writer which will be used to write your summaries to disk:

```
LOGDIR = 'path/to/logsdir' # define your required summary output folder
summary_file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir=LOGDIR)
```

Assuming you may have multiple summaries, merge them to a single op:

```
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

Now, in your training loop, write the summary result:

```
for i in range(NUM_ITR):
    _, summary_res = sess.run([train_op, summary_op])
    summary_file_writer.add_summary(summary_res, global_step=i)
```

To view these summaries, load tensorflow with `logsdir=LOGDIR`.

Comment: what is layer3 here? Suppose I have a model defined, then how can I get info on layers?